# How to prevent loosing git folder after shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, git, clone, repository

I'm using TeaLinux OS, a derivative from Ubuntu.

I just cloned a Git repository, I work on it and shut my PC down.

When I turn my PC on again, I lost the folder.

It happened twice, and now I want some suggestion on how to face this, how to prevent from loosing that folder again?

This happens only on one of my Git folders, the other git folders are working fine.

Comment: Not cloning Git repositories under the `/tmp/` directory. That's how.

Comment: You have provided no information as to where you saved your repository, what happened in between or whenever you have seen any errors in logs. It seems to be an Indonesia based distribution? As @uprego said make sure not use your temp directory, not to use a LiveCD or some other temporary filesystem for cloning your repository. With the information you have provided there is not much more that can be recommended.

Comment: Define "lost"..

Comment: I put the repository in this directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/". I have cloned some other repository before in the same directory, but this is the first time I lost the folder by sudden after shutting down. The other repo folder are still in the same place and nothing happen. But the last repo that I cloned was disappeared. This disappearance happened twice for the same repo folder.